# Getting MAX date from two tables after INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have below tables:

```
declare @tbl1 table (Id1 int, crtdate datetime, InvcNbr varchar(10), ShipperId varchar(10), InvtId varchar(10))
insert into @tbl1 values (1,'01/01/2016','001','S111','111')
insert into @tbl1 values (2,'01/10/2016','002','S111','111')
insert into @tbl1 values (3,'01/02/2016','003','S112','112')
insert into @tbl1 values (4,'01/08/2016','004','S112','112')
insert into @tbl1 values (5,'01/04/2016','005','S113','113')
insert into @tbl1 values (6,'01/05/2016','006','S114','113')

declare @tbl2 table (Id2 int, SerialNo varchar(10), InvcNbr varchar(10), ShipperId varchar(10), InvtId varchar(10))
insert into @tbl2 values (1,'1111111','001','S111','111')
insert into @tbl2 values (2,'1111111','002','S111','111')
insert into @tbl2 values (3,'1111112','003','S112','112')
insert into @tbl2 values (4,'1111112','004','S112','112')
insert into @tbl2 values (5,'1111113','005','S113','113')
insert into @tbl2 values (6,'1111113','006','S114','113')
```

These two tables are related by fields: `InvcNbr, ShipperId and InvtId`

Serials from `@tbl2` are present in two different invoices (`InvcNbr`). How to show only the results from the latest `InvcNbr`

The result should be like this:

```
Id1 crtdate                 InvcNbr ShipperId   InvtId  Id2 SerialNo    InvcNbr ShipperId   InvtId
2   2016-01-10 00:00:00.000 002     S111        111     2   1111111     002     S111        111
4   2016-01-08 00:00:00.000 004     S112        112     4   1111112     004     S112        112
6   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000 006     S114        113     6   1111113     006     S114        113
```

Comment: I'll appreciate if the downvote is commented

Comment: May be you need to put some effort in solving your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below script will give you the desired result..

```
;with cte_1
as
(SELECT Id1,a.crtdate,a.InvcNbr InvcNbr1 ,a.ShipperId ShipperId1 ,a.InvtId InvtId1,b.Id2,b.SerialNo,b.InvcNbr InvcNbr2,b.ShipperId ShipperId2
   ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY b.serialNo ORDER BY a.crtdate desc) Rno
FROM @tbl1 a
JOIN @tbl2 b on a.InvcNbr=b.InvcNbr AND a.ShipperId=b.ShipperId and a.InvtId=b.InvtId)
SELECT  *
FROM cte_1
WHERE Rno=1
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
with lastInvoices as (
        select SerialNo, MAX(InvcNbr) LastInvcNbr
        from @tbl2
        group by SerialNo
    )
select t1.*,t2.*
from lastInvoices li
    join @tbl2 t2 on (li.SerialNo = t2.SerialNo and li.LastInvcNbr=t2.InvcNbr)
    join @tbl1 t1 on (t1.InvcNbr = t2.InvcNbr and t1.ShipperId = t2.ShipperId and t1.InvtId = t2.InvtId)
```